# sshfs: no such file or directory

Tags: sshfs

I just installed `sshfs` and tried to test it out:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
mkdir ~/foo
ssh $server_IP mkdir ~/foo
sshfs $server_IP:~/foo ~/foo
```

Immediately, I get `$server_IP:~/foo: No such file or directory`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are your home directories on both machines at the same location? In the 3rd command, `~/foo` was expanded client-side before sending the command over SSH. In the 4th command, it's either expanded server-side, or not expanded at all. Try just `$server_IP:foo`.

Comment: Argh! I forgot about that. They are the same. It worked with all absolute paths, though. One of the tildes must not have been expanded…

Comment: I guess I'll just have to think of it like `encfs` (and other `FUSE` filesystems?): Always use absolute paths.

Comment: @grawity You can make your comment into an answer; it solved my problem.

Comment: I always wonder...why does sshfs require absolute path? With any other ssh-supported programs, like scp, rsync, `~` expansion has always been assumed. So far, I find sshfs as the only exception

Comment: @Antony All the other FUSE filesystems I've used require absolute paths. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 2):

this happened to me too, so instead of path with `~/some/path` I used the full path, and it worked. so instead of:

`sshfs $server_IP:~/foo ~/foo`

use

`sshfs $server_IP:/Users/bar/foo ~/foo`